# Samsung Galaxy s 3 usb driver

Tags: android, usb, driver

Hello i am trying to develop an android app. I have a Samsung galaxy s 3 but i cannot seem to find driver that are compatible with windows 7. I have the android sdk installed version 1.0.29. I have tried to manually installed the drivers for my device drivers in the usb_driver folder of my sdk. thank you.

Comment: Related: [Driver issues when using Samsung Galaxy SIII via USB for development](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34511/driver-issues-when-using-samsung-galaxy-siii-via-usb-for-development)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you install the Kies Software from Samsung? It comes bundled with correct USB drivers.

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/supportMain.do

The Drivers can be downloaded separately too.

http://androidevolved.com/forums/galaxy-s-iii-root-unroot-roms-kernels-drivers-recovery-etc/1793-samsung-galaxy-s-iii-usb-driver-download.html

In case that doesn't work, Andres Gallos solution might help; I would only attribute this effect to a defective cable tho.

Answer (score 2):

testing on Galaxy, I ran into issues where I had to use the samsung cable to see it work with eclipse.  I changed the cable I was using, and it suddenly worked.  This may not be the issue you are facing, but could save you time if it is. I wasted a bit over an hour finding drivers, but nothing worked other than changing the cable to the samsung cable.

Comment: Please let me know if this solves it. I have been puzzled why switching the cable worked. Whether its a cable issue or a samsung thing. Did not have issue with other test phone brands.

Comment: too long usb cable might be not OK! I was using 0.5 meter and that wasn't great idea.. I used to get driver recognise errors.